# GAE TaskQueue error "taskqueue.BulkAdd failed"

Tags: google-app-engine

Following the documenation here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/taskqueue/push/example

I decided to do a little testing of TaskQueues within my laravel application. Here is my current test code:

```
    $task = new PushTask('/GoogleQueueTest/21',
        ['name' => 'john doe', 'action' => 'send_reminder']);
    $task_name = $task->add();

   return $task_name;
```

resulting in:

```
Remote implementation for taskqueue.BulkAdd failed
```

after alot of searching I cant seem to find why this is not working as expected.